# SymFony DomCrawler id*='text'

Tags: symfony, domcrawler

I'm trying to have DomCrawler select all DIVs that IDs contain "author-"

I currently have

`$list = $crawler->filter('div[id*="actor-"]')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
  return $node->text();
});
var_dump($list);`

But that doesn't return any results, is there any selector like this?

Comment: Paste the relevant part of the content you're trying to crawl please.

Comment: `<div class="filmo-row odd" id="actor-tt0082449"> <span class="year_column"> &nbsp;1981 </span> <b><a href="/title/tt0082449/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1">Ghost Story</a></b> <br> Ricky Hawthorne </div>` is the HTML, I'm trying to get `Ghost Story`

Comment: xabbuh's solution is the right one. If it doesn't work for you, then you must be loading a different document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) in your XPath like this:

```
$list = $crawler->filterXPath('div[contains(@id, "actor-")]')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
  return $node->text();
});
var_dump($list);
```

Edit: From the conversation below, the XPath should be `div[contains(@id, "actor-")]/b/a`.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\SyntaxErrorException' with message 'Expected operator, but <delimiter "(" at 12>

Comment: I changed filter to filterXPath and it's still empty

Comment: Sorry, the answer should indeed have used the `filterXPath()` method (I updated it). Can you show a small example HTML string where this does not work?

Comment: `<div class="filmo-row odd" id="actor-tt0082449">
<span class="year_column">
&nbsp;1981
</span>
<b><a href="/title/tt0082449/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1">Ghost Story</a></b>
<br>
Ricky Hawthorne
</div>`

I'm trying to get "Ghost Story"

Comment: Sorry if this is super simple, this is my first time ever using SymFony

Comment: Looks like you then want to replace `author-` in the XPath with `actor-`. By the way, you will also have to filter this a bit more as you are only interested in the content of the a element.

Comment: Well that was a massive derp on my part, how would I filter it more? add ->filter('b > a') after the filterXPath?

Comment: You be able to do that with a single XPath expression like `div[contains(@id, "author-")]/b/a` (I didn't test it). But the actual solution depends on how your HTML documents look like (it might be trickier if you have variants of it).

Comment: Please make sure to replace `author-` with `actor-` in the XPath from my last comment.

Comment: I did, I have it
`filterXPath('div[contains(@id, "actor-")]/b/a')`  but it still returns `array(0) { }`

Comment: That works for me. I guess that's related to some other code you have then.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you might need to add two slashes before the div (or whatever element you're targeting), like so: `filterXPath('//div[contains(@id, "actor-")]')`.